# New html5 input type still work with doctype html4

Tags: html, doctype

I read DOCTYPE definion from [w3cschool](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

> it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the
>   page is written in.

To understand, I try to use a new `html5` input type with doctype `html4` (I find new html5 input type from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <input type="datetime-local"> 
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I run it on `Chrome`, this input type still working fine. I think it will not working. What is my misunderstand?
Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: It's a good question.  I think the browser is being nice and accepting it.  But, this is declared in strict mode.  Hmm...

Comment: Thank you. I just have a thinking like: maybe if doctype < current browser support, browser will use current browser support for display. If doctype > current browser support, maybe they will show some error or notification but I can not test it

Comment: Simply don't believe what w3schools says. The browser does not care what version the HTML is written in. Browsers just support HTML, period.